# Is AES practically unbreakable?

Tags: encryption, aes, cryptanalysis, brute-force-attack

Is AES practically unbreakable? Is brute force attack practical on AES?

Comment: Besides the question linked above (of which this is a duplicate), the following AES-related Q&A might be interesting for you to read: [Is AES-256 a post-quantum secure cipher or not?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/6712/12164)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute force attack on a randomly chosen AES key is impractical for the foreseeable future.  With quantum computing some experts expect that a 128-bit key could be broken in our lifetime, but not a 256-bit key.

That said, plenty of systems using AES have been broken--using a secure block cipher does not magically make your system secure.