# cascade encryption - If I encrypt my data using many different encryption algorithms

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, homomorphic-encryption

If I encrypt my data using many different encryption algorithms (using different passwords)

how will an adversary be able to decipher the message?

Comment: We have many questions and answer for this. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=cascade and note that we don't use passwords for keys, we use Key Derivation functions to derive keys from passwords. What is the strength of each password? Why do you need this? Why not AES-256?

Comment: thank you ... we didn't think that DES would be broken ... and etc ...SHA-1, MD-5, RSA-1024, and Dual Elliptic Curve DRGB all had to be replaced by incompatible alternatives ... AES-256 will also also be retired - https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6712/is-aes-256-a-post-quantum-secure-cipher-or-not#:~:text=As%20such%2C%20AES%2D256%20is,set%20keysize%20is%20safe%20indefinitely.